# SQL query results not add up when using a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

What could be causing my second SQL query to return less than the expected count? I have an address table with 1000 entries, and my first query returns 100 when filtering for 'New York' city and 'Mainstreet' street. The second query should return 900, but it's not. Here are my queries:

```
select count(*)
from address_data
where city = 'New York' and street = 'Mainstreet'

select count(*)
from address_data
where not (city = 'New York' and street = 'Mainstreet')
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is related with the `NULL` values as mentioned within the current answer. You might convert the condition of the second query to the following `WHERE 
 (NOT ( city = 'New York' AND street = 'Mainstreet')
  AND   city IS NOT NULL
  AND street IS NOT NULL)
   OR city IS NULL 
   OR street IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
--  S a m p l e   d a t a :
WITH
    tbl (ID, CITY, STREET) AS 
        (
            Select 1, 'New York', 'Main Street' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'New York', 'NOT Main Street' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'NOT New York', 'Main Street' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'New York', Null From Dual 
        )

-- Your 2nd query returns 2 instead of 3 as count
Select Count(*) "CNT"
From tbl
Where CITY = 'New York' and STREET = 'Main Street'

-- Options for your 2nd query that all return 3 as count

-- Posssible Null values replaced with '-' for comparison
-- using NOT (condition 1 And condition 2)
Select Count(*) "CNT"
From tbl
Where Not (Nvl(CITY, '-') = 'New York' And Nvl(STREET, '-') = 'Main Street')

-- Posssible Null values replaced with '-' for comparison
-- using negative Condition 1 OR negative Condition 2
Select Count(*) "CNT"
From tbl
Where Nvl(CITY, '-') != 'New York' OR Nvl(STREET, '-') != 'Main Street'

-- using negative Condition 1 OR negative Condition 2
-- additional testing for null values separately
Select Count(*) "CNT"
From tbl
Where CITY != 'New York' OR CITY Is Null OR STREET != 'Main Street' OR STREET Is Null
```

Comment: Your last query delivered the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Conditions.html#GUID-C2E3ED44-16E7-4924-9125-E1693B1022A8):

> A condition specifies a combination of one or more expressions and logical (Boolean) operators and returns a value of `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `UNKNOWN`.

In the section on [`NULL`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071) you'll find this clarification:

> To test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. **If you use any other condition with nulls and the result depends on the value of the null, then the result is `UNKNOWN`**. Because null represents a lack of data, a null cannot be equal or unequal to any value or to another null. However, Oracle considers two nulls to be equal when evaluating a `DECODE` function.

As long as `where` clause returns only rows where condition evaluates to `TRUE` (so it rejects `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`), `NOT (<condition>)` will not provide you rows with `UNKNOWN` condition value.

Considering this sample data:

> ```
> create table sample_tab(col) as
>   select 'True' from dual union all
>   select 'False' from dual union all
>   select null from dual
> ```

You may use [`LNNVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LNNVL.html#GUID-FBCCE9B1-614E-45FA-8EE1-DFAA4F936867) function to catch everything that is not `TRUE`:

```
select *
from sample_tab
where lnnvl(col = 'True')
```

Or use pure set approach and calculate set complement with `EXCEPT` (`MINUS` in Oracle pre-19c) set operator:

```
select *
from sample_tab

except

select *
from sample_tab
where col = 'True'
```

In both cases you'll get the same result:

| COL |
| --- |
| False |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SjQFwi_Y)

Answer (score 0):

I think NULL values in the city and street columns are not identified in your second query. So may be can you try your second query like below; and see:

```
select count(*)
from address_data
where (NVL(city, '') != 'New York' OR NVL(street, '') != 'Mainstreet'))
```

Comment: you're correct. Any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: Still less results.

Comment: That's because query isn't correct. In Oracle, empty string is *equal* to NULL so suggested NVL doesn't actually do anything. Should be something like `where nvl(city, 'x') <> 'New York' ...` (i.e. use any character you find appropriate).

Comment: Still the counts do not add up. I'm wondering what causes this.

Comment: Post some sample data that illustrate the problem.

Comment: Because `not(A and B)` is `(not A) OR (not B)`. That's why it's worth to put `not` on the entire condition rather than push it into individual parts (and it's also more readable: you may explicitly see what is negated instead of building a truth table for two predicates)